# I have installed a node based API from https://github.com/opentok/interactive-broadcast-api, but how to enable HTTPS on this API?

Tags: node.js, express, opentok

Normally, I use https.createServer method to server my node application over HTTPS, but in this case, I am not sure.

Apparently this is the code,

**INDEX.JS**

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _config = require('./config/config');

var _config2 = _interopRequireDefault(_config);

var _express = require('./config/express');

var _express2 = _interopRequireDefault(_express);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

// config should be imported before importing any other file
var debug = require('debug')('ibs-backend:index');

// make bluebird default Promise
Promise = require('bluebird'); // eslint-disable-line no-global-assign

// module.parent check is required to support mocha watch
// src: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1912
if (!module.parent) {
  // listen on port config.port
  _express2.default.listen(_config2.default.port, function () {
    debug('server started on port ' + _config2.default.port + ' (' + _config2.default.env + ')');
  });
}

exports.default = _express2.default;
module.exports = exports['default'];
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

**config/express.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import expressJwt from 'express-jwt';
import logger from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import compress from 'compression';
import methodOverride from 'method-override';
import cors from 'cors';
import httpStatus from 'http-status';
import expressWinston from 'express-winston';
import expressValidation from 'express-validation';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import winstonInstance from './winston';
import routes from '../server/routes/index.route';
import config from './config';
import APIError from '../server/helpers/APIError';

const app = express();

if (config.env === 'development') {
  app.use(logger('dev'));
}

/* Define the routes that work without a JWT token */
const allowedPaths = [
  '/api/auth/token',
  '/api/auth/token-fan',
  '/api/auth/token-celebrity',
  '/api/auth/token-host',
  '/api/event/get-events-by-admin',
  '/api/event/get-current-admin-event'
];

// parse body params and attache them to req.body
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressJwt({ secret: config.jwtSecret }).unless({ path: allowedPaths }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(compress());
app.use(methodOverride());

// secure apps by setting various HTTP headers
app.use(helmet());

// enable CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing
app.use(cors());

// enable detailed API logging in dev env
if (config.env === 'development') {
  expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body');
  expressWinston.responseWhitelist.push('body');
  app.use(expressWinston.logger({
    winstonInstance,
    meta: true, // optional: log meta data about request (defaults to true)
    msg: 'HTTP {{req.method}} {{req.url}} {{res.statusCode}} {{res.responseTime}}ms',
    colorStatus: true // Color the status code (default green, 3XX cyan, 4XX yellow, 5XX red).
  }));
}

// mount all routes on /api path
app.use('/api', routes);

// if error is not an instanceOf APIError, convert it.
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err instanceof expressValidation.ValidationError) {
    // validation error contains errors which is an array of error each containing message[]
    const unifiedErrorMessage = err.errors.map(error => error.messages.join('. ')).join(' and ');
    const error = new APIError(unifiedErrorMessage, err.status, true);
    return next(error);
  } else if (!(err instanceof APIError)) {
    const apiError = new APIError(err.message, err.status, err.isPublic);
    return next(apiError);
  }
  return next(err);
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new APIError('API not found', httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  return next(err);
});

// log error in winston transports except when executing test suite
if (config.env !== 'test') {
  app.use(expressWinston.errorLogger({
    winstonInstance
  }));
}

// error handler, send stacktrace only during development
app.use((err, req, res, next) => // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  res.status(err.status).json({
    message: err.isPublic ? err.message : httpStatus[err.status],
    stack: config.env === 'development' ? err.stack : {}
  })
);

export default app;
```

Normally, I can use letsencrypt ssl with nodejs applications like this

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello!\n');
}).listen(443);
```

But in this particular scenario, I cant understand, how to do it.

This is the  [github repository](https://github.com/opentok/interactive-broadcast-api)

Thanks for your replies in advance.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: ``` index.js

if (!module.parent) {
  // listen on port config.port
  _express2.default.listen(_config2.default.port, function () {
    debug('server started on port ' + _config2.default.port + ' (' + _config2.default.env + ')');
  });
}

````

_express2 objected is created from through this code.

[link](https://github.com/opentok/interactive-broadcast-api/blob/master/config/express.js)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `express` app instance to `https.createServer()`, since express was meant to be used this way.

```js
// We need to import https!
const https = require("https");
// Or, like this
import https from "https";
// Define the key and certificate.
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};
// Then...
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

It should work the same as any other express app.

Here is a link for more information on that: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this, by installing SSL through Nginx. I have included all certificates in Nginx site configuration and it worked very well.

Thank you for your help.